# Plotting extreme negative and positive values

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I have a dataframe with three values, i would like to plot as a bar chart. I am having an issue with extreme values, I tried taking a log, but it can't handle negative values, can you please help me to plot bar charts which scaled enough to make sense.

| Head | Values |
| --- | --- |
| A | -1,000,000,000 |
| B | -650,000 |
| C | 9,500 |

Answer (score 2):

You can simply change the [scale](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale.html) with [`symlog`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.SymmetricalLogScale):

```
ax = df.plot.bar(x='Head', y='Values')
ax.set_yscale('symlog')
# ax.set_ylim((-1e9, 1e6))  # manual y-lim
ylim = np.max(np.abs(ax.get_ylim()))
ax.set_ylim(-ylim, ylim)  # symetric y-lim
ax.axhline(0, color='grey')  # suggested by @JohanC
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `ax.axhline(0, color='grey')` would add a line at `y=0`, which might help in the visualization.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC. I updated my answer per your advice.